# How to insert unicode string in Database using Pyodbc with python2.7

Tags: python, sql, unicode, pyodbc

Below is my sample code :

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', \
                   server = 'localhost', \
                   uid = 'sa', \
                   pwd = '1234', \
                   autocommit = True, trusted_connection='yes', database = 'DB')                       
Objcursor = conn.cursor()
mystring1 = "MÜNRÜC"
mystring = mystring1.decode("utf-8",'replace')
sql = "INSERT INTO system (name) VALUES ('%s')" %(mystring)
Objcursor.execute(sql)
conn.Commit()
```

When I run this code snippet, I get output as "M?N?R?C" since I have used replace while encoding.
if I do not use replace it gives an error doesn't encode the string.
can someone please help on how to insert the  unicode string using pyodbc in database without replacing the character/data loss.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback (error) you get if you do not use the 'replace' option?

Comment: Thanks for quick response it gives an error as :'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you may be constrained by other factors but it would be a good idea to stop using python 2.7 since it is now unsupported.

Secondly, you don't seem to have declared the encoding of your source file so `mystring1 = "MÜNRÜC"` probably isn't doing what you think it is.

Solution:

You should explicitly declare the encoding of your source file and it is probably sensible to *only* use unicode objects (not python 2.7 strings).  You can do this explicitly like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{SQL Server}', \
                   server = 'localhost', \
                   uid = 'sa', \
                   pwd = '1234', \
                   autocommit = True, trusted_connection='yes', database = 'DB')            

objcursor = conn.cursor()  # lowercase names
name_unicode = u"MÜNRÜC"  # descriptive variable name
sql = u"INSERT INTO system (name) VALUES ('%s')" % name_unicode  # unicode objects
objcursor.execute(sql)
conn.Commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario I will not be able to add /modify the variable name_unicode since it is data which I am getting from a file,which doesn't have suffix 'u'. I tried adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- but it didn't work.please help. Also this same scenario works well with python 3 since in python3 default value is unicode butin case of python2 this fails.

Comment: If you're getting it from a file then you need to work out what the file encoding is (because it apparently ain't utf8).